# Getting a proper value from RegQueryValueEx

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I am trying to extract a value from the windows registry of type `REG_SZ`, using `RegQueryValueEx`, I got the value except it was riddled with strange "\000" before each letter.To show you what I mean here are some images:

Value I want(It is a device name of a wireless adapter)
[image]

Value I got:

[image]

here is the code:

```
    HKEY hlistkey = NULL;
    HKEY hkey = NULL;

    int dwIndex=0;

    string devName = returndevName(); //return current selected device name using iphlpapi.h  
    WCHAR KeyNameBuf[512];
    DWORD keyNameSizBuf = 512;

    char buffer[512];


    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}") ,0,KEY_READ, &hlistkey );
    if(!hlistkey)
    {
        cout << "failed" << endl;
    }
    while(RegEnumKeyEx(hlistkey,dwIndex++,KeyNameBuf,&keyNameSizBuf,0,NULL,NULL,NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {

        RegOpenKeyEx(hlistkey, KeyNameBuf, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_SET_VALUE, &hkey);
        if(hkey)
        {
            keyNameSizBuf = 512;
            if(RegQueryValueEx(hkey,TEXT("NetCfgInstanceId"), 0,NULL,(LPBYTE)buffer,&keyNameSizBuf ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
            {
                if(strcmp(buffer,devName.c_str() ) ==0)
                {
                    //set value here
                }
            }
            RegCloseKey(hkey);
        }        
    }
}
```

comparing `buffer` and `devName` would not be the same because of the extra null characters .If I cast buffer to a string I simply got a "{" which is the first value.I need to get the value of the `devename` in the registry before I can change the "NetworkAddress" in the registry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using `WCHAR`, I assume you are compiling with Unicode support. If this is true, then also the `buffer` needs to be `WCHAR`.

Comment: i am using netbeans with Mingw as the compiler(because i am also using QT),i am not sure how to set unicode support, but is it because of unicode i got the nulls in buffer? If i set buffer as type WCHAR then how do i compare buffer with devname.

Comment: @cftmon yes, you get the nulls because you are putting a unicode string in an ansi buffer. There are various ways to compare to devname: 1. use std::wstring for devname; 2. convert the unicode string to ansi; 3. force the use of ansi version of registry function by placing an `A` at the end (and use char instead of WCHAR)